# Auto run the programs When the system turns on(Debian)

Tags: debian, startup, c++

I've got a beaglebone black that has Debian 9.1. we wrote a c++ program for its GPIOs and We want this program to always run when the system turns on.
how can we do that?

Comment: You have to you use systemd unit for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extremely *simple* solution would be to add a `@reboot` cron job that just runs the binary.

Do `crontab -e` for the user that needs to run the code (e.g. `sudo crontab -e` for roots crontab), and add the line

```
@reboot /path/to/some/executable
```

This will schedule the job to run each time the system has booted up.

See the `crontab(5)` manual for more info (`man 5 crontab`).

Depending on what the program does, this may be enough, or it may be too simplistic.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, this edits the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>` that is not accessible for a normal user though.

Comment: @user136036 Why would it need to be? The `crontab` command will have ability to create the appropriate files in that directory depending on what user is invoking it.  Also, the actual location of the user-specific crontabs various depending on the system's configuration. On OpenBSD it's `/var/cron/tabs/`, but it doesn't matter to the user.

Comment: Because it's good to know where stuff is, and if someone had written my comment, I could have saved a minute to google my question :)

Comment: @user136036 Well, since those files shouldn't be touched by anything other than the cron-related tools, I find it hard to comprehend why knowing where these files are stored would be helpful to anyone.  Note that if you modify these files by other means than through `crontab`, you would have to take extra measures to make sure that the cron daemon knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the program to say `run_gpio` and save it in a known path, e.g. `/path/to/run_gpio`. It has to be marked executable for root:

`$ sudo chmod 755 /path/to/run_gpio`

Then configure Debian's `init` system to start your program.

You can find an explanation e.g. here: 
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-automatically-start-program-on-boot-in-debian.html

> In Debian, a directory called /etc/init.d contains a list of scripts
>   that are executed by init process during startup and shutdown. Thus,
>   in order to automatically run a particular program or script at
>   startup, you can create a corresponding init.d script.
>
> `$ sudo vi /etc/init.d/run_gpio`
>   Instead of vi, you can also use nano.
>
> Put these lines in the new file within the init.d directory:
>
> `#! /bin/sh`
>   `# /etc/init.d/run_gpio`
>   `case "$1" in   start)`
>   `/path/to/run_gpio`
>   `;; esac`
>
> Finally, make the init.d script executable, and add the init.d
>   script to a default runlevel, so that the script can be called at boot
>   time (and also during shutdown).
>
> `$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/run_gpio`
>   `$ sudo update-rc.d run_gpio defaults`

Comment: Recent Debian uses `systemd` ....